# Handle custom errors with all http verbs in mvc5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, custom-errors

Hi I am developing web application in mvc5. I am handling errors using custom errors and the code snippet I have in my web.config is given below:

```
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Login/Error/" mode="On" >
  </customErrors>
```

I have controller Login and action method Error

```
  public ActionResult Error()
  {
    return View();
  }
```

Below is the code to hide iis version.

```
  <customHeaders>  
  <remove name="X-Powered-By" /> 
  </customHeaders>
```

It works as expected.
When i try to access the url http://localhost:62777/dashboardtest with PUT verb(this does not exist) in my httprequester i get iis version. 
Attached screen shot below.

[image: IIS version with PUT method]

Same url if I hit with GET method iis version is not visible. 
Screen shot below.

[image: IIS version with GET method]

I'd like to know how to hide iis version with all http verbs? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.